# Keyboard layout chromatic visual indicator

Tags: gnome, 18.04, keyboard-layout, indicator

I touch type using a keyboard with a German layout but other than German I switch the layout with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to US and Greek layout.

When using a large monitor its a pain having to steer my view to the top left of the monitor to view the current layout. Is there a visual indicator using a chromatic code that can be assessed by one's peripheral vision aiding in speed when touch typing while switching layouts?

I am OK with any suggestions that include coding/gobbling something up from scratch or using some scriptable applet.

I currently use Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3 if it's of any use.